# How to integrate baguetteBox.js in the BST WordPress Starter theme?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, wordpress-theming

I am trying to modify the starter WordPress theme BST for a personal project.

In it I want to have a custom page template with bootstrap elements. This page will show various images in the form of galleries.

I also need to import the baguetteBox.js plugin so that I can use its lightbox effect.

The pages have been created in html and they work. The custom page template is created and the design is the same as the html variant.

However when importing the scripts in WordPress (by using wp enque and wp register) the console cannot define baguetteBox. So I guess I am doing something wrong.

[Here is the official guide](https://github.com/feimosi/baguetteBox.js/) on installing this Bootstrap plugin:

The enqueue code that I am using is placed in the `bst-master/function/enqueues.php` file:

**For baguetteBox.min.js:**

```
wp_register_script('baguetteBox-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/baguetteBox.min.js', false, null, true, array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('baguetteBox-js');
```

I have also tried without array('jquery') - no changes. I am also not sure where/how to place the **"async"** part (as recommended by the developers).

**For baguetteBox.min.css:**

```
wp_register_style('baguetteBox-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/baguetteBox.min.css', false, null);
wp_enqueue_style('baguetteBox-css');
```

**The problem is with the** `<script>baguetteBox.run('.tz-gallery', {filter: /.angelov.+\.(gif|jpe?g|png|webp)/i});</script>` which I cannot figure out how and where to place so I just tried to add it inside the page template php file and also in the Insert Headers/Footers plugin.

Comment: Amongst maybe other things, your register code is wrong.
`wp_register_script('baguetteBox-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/baguetteBox.min.js', false, null, true, array('jquery'));` does not follow the syntax as per DOC which is `wp_register_script( string $handle, string|bool $src, string[] $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )` and hence your script should be `wp_register_script('baguetteBox-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/baguetteBox.min.js', array(), false, true);`

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out my own solution. First of all the classic (and recommended) way of adding scripts for WordPress was failing somehow. So I decided to place the script in the header.php file before the closing head tag and without async. I also moved the script in the js folder of the child theme.
It looks like this:

```
    <script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/js/baguetteBox.min.js"> </script>
```

Next I placed the below code in the custom page template file right after the final closing `<div>` tag:

```
    <script>baguetteBox.run('.tz-gallery', {filter:/.angelov.+\.(gif|jpe?g|png|webp)/i});</script>
```

And it all worked out like a charm.